# Elements In Array Being Ignored

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

For some strange reason 2 of the elements in my arrays are being ignored. They are... 
`ETIQUETAS XTRA MINI PARA OBJETOS` and `ETIQUETAS TERMOAHDESIVAS CLASICAS`.

If the product page title is included in the array it renders an info box on the product page below the product image. This is true for all products in the array except the 2 mentioned above.

Below I have the two array vars and below that... the code that renders the info boxes. Any help is greatly appreciated. By the way, this is WooCommerce over Wordpress 4.0.

```
<?php

//for every label product.
$infoBox1Array = array('Pack Duo','Etiquetas Grandes','Etiquetas Navideñas','Pack Trio','ETIQUETAS PARA CUMPLEAÑOS SUPER PERSONALIZADA','LETREROS PARA CASAS','ETIQUETAS PARA CUMPLEAÑOS','PACK ZAPATOS FORMAS DE PIE','Pack Zapatos','Etiquetas Para Alergias Personalizadas','PACK FULL COLOR','Membretes','Etiquetas Termoadhesivas Mini (fondo blanco)','ETIQUETAS TERMOADHESIVAS FULL COLOR','ETIQUETAS TERMOAHDESIVAS CLASICAS','Saca & Pega','Stickers para Carros','ETIQUETAS PARA ALERGIAS','Etiquetas Kosher','Etiquetas Cocina','Etiquetas Minis','Pack mix 3','Pack mix 2','Pack mix 1','Etiquetas Redondas','Etiquetas Medianas','ETIQUETAS XTRA MINI PARA OBJETOS','Pack Xpress','Pack Guarderia','Pack Regreso al Cole');

//for every product that can be personalized.
$infoBox2Array = array('Pack Duo','Etiquetas Grandes','Etiquetas Navideñas','Pack Trio','ETIQUETAS PARA CUMPLEAÑOS SUPER PERSONALIZADA','LETREROS PARA CASAS','ETIQUETAS PARA CUMPLEAÑOS','PACK ZAPATOS FORMAS DE PIE','Pack Zapatos','Etiquetas Para Alergias Personalizadas','PACK FULL COLOR','Membretes','Etiquetas Termoadhesivas Mini (fondo blanco)','ETIQUETAS TERMOADHESIVAS FULL COLOR','ETIQUETAS TERMOAHDESIVAS CLASICAS','Saca & Pega','Etiquetas Minis','Pack mix 3','Pack mix 2','Pack mix 1','Etiquetas Redondas','Etiquetas Medianas','ETIQUETAS XTRA MINI PARA OBJETOS','Pack Xpress','Pack Guarderia','Pack Regreso al Cole');

?>

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <?php
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/info-box-arrays.php');
        if(is_single( $infoBox1Array )) {
            echo '


            <div style="background-color: #ffffff; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;padding: 7px"><p style="text-align: justify">
                El tamaño de la etiqueta y de letra son aproximados.<br/>
                Los colores pueden variar de acuerdo a la configuración de su pantalla. 
            </p></div>

            <div style="clear: both">&nbsp;</div>';
        }

        if(is_single( $infoBox2Array )) {
            echo '
            <div style="background-color: #ffffff; border: solid 1px #CCCCCC;padding: 7px"><p style="text-align: justify">
                <strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">Nota Importante:</span></strong> Los datos que escribe son los que serán procesados en su pedido.</br/>
                Considerar acentos y mayusculas. 
            </p></div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are those product titles?

Comment: Yes. Here is the website... http://esoesmio.net/

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working. What happens if you substitute one of those titles out for its product ID? Does it work then?

Comment: What is_single() function does?

Comment: @mevius I took your advice and used the product SKU and it worked for one product (etiquetas-termoahdesivas-clasicas) but not the other. For the other I used the post id (171) and that worked. This is why I hat wordpress functions; they are so inconsistent. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code and created a post ETIQUETAS TERMOAHDESIVAS CLASICAS. It works fine so I suspect that there is nothing wrong with your array.

I think that there is another reason that is_single is returning false. I think it is either you have a slightly different title for your post or that you are trying to use it for a page.

Comment: Thank you for your input Sir. I took Mevius' advice and use the post id and product sku for the other. I'll have to find a more reliable function that can work outside of the wordpress loop.